# Oracle APEX, making a page expire after a set amount of time

Tags: javascript, oracle

I have the following situation:
A user wants to reset their password, the application sends them an email which contains the url to the page where they can reset the password.

My question is, is it possible within APEX to make a page expire lets say 5 minutes after the application sends the email to the user? Is there a built-in function for this or maybe some javascript code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is wondering on how to do this, It's one way to create an Authorization Scheme for the page, based on a boolean PL/SQL expression.

When a user sends the email, the current time gets saved into an application item in session state, and when the link in the email gets clicked, before the page is loaded, the application checks if the (current date - date when email was sent) is more than 5 minutes, if it is, the Authorization Scheme fails and the page won't get loaded.